# How to sort dependentObservable PagedList Data in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have created a Page with Pagination option. 
Code looks same like : http://blog.ryanvanderpol.com/index.php/2012/07/using-knockoutjs-to-create-an-edit-in-place-data-grid/

Now am not able to add  sorting to the dependentObservable PagedList Data in knockout js

because PagedList  is not having Sort() prpoerty ..

Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace something like this:

```
self.someArray = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return [someDependency()];
});
```

with this:

```
self.someArray = ko.observableArray();
ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    self.someArray([someDependency()]);
});

// now you can call sort on someArray
var sortedArray = self.someArray.sort();
```

You can use dependentObserable/computed to compute new value of other observable without returning any value.

Answer (score 1):

You could change his viewmodel to use a computed instead of an observable array perhaps?

Here's an example

```
self.list = ko.observableArray(initialData);

self.sortProperty = ko.observable('propertyNameInRowObject');

self.sortedList = ko.computed( function() {
    var sorted = self.list.sort( self.sortFn );    
    return sorted;
};

self.sortFn = function(a, b) {
    if ( a[self.sortProperty()] > b[self.sortProperty()] ) {
        return 1
    }
    else if ( a[self.sortProperty()] < b[self.sortProperty()] ) {
        return -1
    }
    else { 
        return 0
    }
}

self.onColumnClicked = function(e) {
    var colName = e.target.Name; // probably something like this...
    if ( colName === 'xyz' ) {
        self.sortProperty('xyzProperty');
    }
}
```

Sorry, my javascript is a bit rusty, I've been doing most of mine in coffeescript

Comment: Hi Neil , Thanks for the answer . This works fine if i want to sort data initially . But i have to sort data on column click of PagedList there am not able to do .

Comment: @Basavaraj - Hi, I've updated my answer for you.  The computed should recompute when you change the `sortProperty`.  You might need to make the sort function more generic if you're sorting on a number or a string.

Comment: @Basavaraj if the computed doesn't automatically recompute then you could do something like `self.sortProperty.subscribe( runSort )` where runSort would be a function that recomputed `self.sortedList` manually